# Get database value based on dropdown value in Codeigniter using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I want to retrieve value from database based on dropdown value using the ajax.
Here I'm attaching the screenshot thats what exactly I need. Once we change the year the result should be changed.

So please help me to do this task. Thanks in Advance :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it:

1. On drop down change you can reload the entire page with appending the year in url of the page and show your result on the basis of that url appended year value.
2. You can use ajax call on change of year drop down and load the specific content in a div.

ajax method:

```
var dropdownSelection = $('#dropdown_id').val();
$.ajax({
    url         : 'proccess.php',
    method      : 'get',
    data       :
    {
        selection : dropdownSelection,

    },
    success    : function(response)
    {
        $('#div_result').html(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#district").change(function() {
    var vdcID = {"district_id" : $('#district').val()};
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: vdcID,
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/ajax/showVdcById",
      dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      $('#vdc').html("<option>Please Select VDC</option>  ");
        $.each(data, function(i, data){
             $('#vdc').append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+data+"</option>");
        });
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

this code might help you. it takes value from from a dropdown and updates value on another dropdown based on the id it sends to database

Comment: Thanks. This solution helped me to reach to the solution somewhat .

Comment: Brother, it's helped me a lot and I would like to upvote but StackOverflow is not allowing me to do that. :( I don't have much reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Add onchange event updateMonths() to year select tag

```
function updateMonths()
    {
        var selectedYear    =   $('#year').val();

        if(selectedYear!= "")
        {

            $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      data: { "year":selectedYear },
                      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/ajax/getAllMonths",
                      dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){

                            $.each(data, function(i, data){

                                $('#month').append($('<option>', {
                                            value: i,
                                            text: data
                                    }));
                            });
                        }
                    }); 
        }       
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to update the value in month drop down. I just want to pass the value to my controller when we select any of the year.